# SQLAlchemy automap - adding methods to automapped Model

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a preexisting database that I'm using with SQLAlchemy, so I'm using automap to get the Models from the database. What is the best way to add methods to these classes? For example, for a User class, I'd like to add methods such as verifying the password. Also, I'd like to add methods for flask-login (UserMixin) methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Specify your classes explicitly](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#specifying-classes-explicitly) beforehand, and define your methods as you would normally:

```
Base = automap_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    def verify_password(self, password):
        ...

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

Now `Base.classes.User` and `User` are the same, with your additional methods. To make your `User` class flask-login compatible, implement the [listed attributes and methods](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class), or add the provided [`UserMixin`](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/master/flask_login/mixins.py#L12) to your `User` class. The mixin seems to only expect the existence of an `id` attribute/column from your `User` class.

Comment: In the class, do I only have to implement the methods, since automap will fill in other things such as attributes?

Comment: Pretty much, automap will provide the columns.

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I received error: "ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Users|Users could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'Users'". (I have composite primary keys, but automap works fine when I do not try to pre-declare.)

Comment: @rafz Cannot reproduce, automapping a table with a composite primary key, while defining additional methods on mapped class works just fine. Please create a question, with a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure that you tick all 3 boxes; others must be able to take your example code, run it, and verify the results.