# SQLAlchemy - add mixin class to Automaped classes

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and am generating classes dynamically for my database via the [Automapping functionality](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html).

I need to add a Mixin class with various helper methods to each of these automapped classes.

I tried to create subclasses of the automapped class with the mixin class:

```
db = create_engine(connection_string)
automapper = automap_base()
automapper.prepare(db, reflect=True)
for class_variable in automapper.__subclasses__():
    new_class = type(class_variable.__name__, (class_variable, Mixins), {})
```

when I try to use these classes I get errors like:

```
class _ is a subclass of AutomapBase.  Mappings are not produced until the .prepare() method is called on the class hierarchy.
```

If I call automapper.prepare() again, I get warnings like this and mostly just enters an infinite loop:

```
SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as sqlalchemy.ext.automap.payments, and will be replaced in the string-lookup table.
```

I cannot [specify the classes explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39417527/1316252) as in this answer, because I don't know the database tables ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#augmenting-the-base), you can augment the Base with your Mixin class. In this case, you could pass your Mixin as the `cls` parameter.

```
automapper = automap_base(cls=Mixin)
```

Comment: To extend on this answer, Simon from the mailing list explained:

"If you want to add your methods to *every* automapped class, you can
change the base class used by automap_base(). Something like this:

automapper = automap_base(cls=MySpecialBaseClass)
This works because automap_base passes most of its arguments on to
declarative_base:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.automap_base
and declarative_base accepts a "cls" argument which is used as the base class"